# JS add array in tracking code push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, array-push, criteo

I've been trying since yesterday to pass an array in a push method.

There is a tracking code called Criteo and they required to fill the following to make it work. Everything's fine except the viewBasket.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
  window.criteo_q.push(
  { event: "setAccount", account: 11111 },
  { event: "setEmail", email: "username@domain.com" },
  { event: "setSiteType", type: "d" },
  { event: "viewBasket", item: [
    { id: "product_id_1", price: price_1, quantity: quantity_1 },
    { id: "product_id_2", price: price_2, quantity: quantity_2 }
    /* add a line for each item in the user's basket */
  ]}
);
</script>
```

So I created an array and populated it with the data Criteo requires (which is the product id, the price and the quantity). Although in the console I could see the correct structure, when I pass it in the code it does not work.

In the console I can see this (first part is the two lines I pushed into array, and second one is the whole array):

```
{ id:"20020-278", price: 119, quantity: 1},
{ id:"20009-129", price: 927, quantity: 3},

Array[2]
0: "{ id:"20020-278", price: 119, quantity: 1},"
1: "{ id:"20009-129", price: 927, quantity: 3},"
length: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

Exactly as I want it but for some reason it does not work. I tried to convert it to JSON array or just pass a normal line with no variables and I still have this problem. I also escaped that symbol **{** ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    ...
    var full_line = "\{ id:\""+pid+"\", price: "+price+", quantity: "+quantity+"\},";
    //var full_line = "\{ id:20020-278, price:119, quantity:1\},";
    //var full_lineJson = JSON.stringify(full_line);

    console.log(full_line);
    allitems.push(full_line);
</script>
```

I pass the 'allitems' array in Criteo code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
  window.criteo_q.push(
  { event: "setAccount", account: 11111 },
  { event: "setEmail", email: "username@domain.com" },
  { event: "setSiteType", type: "d" },
  { event: "viewBasket", item: [
         allitems
  ]}
);
</script>
```

On Criteo debug page is displayed like this:

[image]

The result should be:

```
Product ID   Price   Quantity
20010-278      69       1
```

But as you can see the structure is broken somehow. I tried so many different ways and still didn't manage to fix this. There is something wrong with the structure in array but I am not sure what else I can do. Any suggestions please?

**EDIT: If I pass an object**

```
Object {product_id: "20020-278", price: "119", quantity: "1"}
Object {product_id: "20009-129", price: "927", quantity: "3"}

Array[2]
0: Object
price: "119"
product_id: "20020-278"
quantity: "1"

__proto__: Object

1: Object
price: "927"
product_id: "20009-129"
quantity: "3"

__proto__: Object

length: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

Criteo site displays this error when I use objects:
Product ID info missing: "item" property is missing

Code I used for objects:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var full_line = {};
        full_line.product_id = product_id;
        full_line.price = price;
        full_line.quantity = quantity;
    allitems.push(full_line);
    ...
</script>
```

Then I just used the allitems inside the Criteo "viewBasket", item property.

Comment: If this is the output in console: `0: "{ id:"20020-278", price: 119, quantity: 1},"`, you are pushing string, and not object

Comment: do I need to push an object? I wanted to follow 100% the structure from Criteo. which is this (including all the symbols): { id: "product_id_1", price: price_1, quantity: quantity_1 },

Comment: Criteo **is** using an object.

Comment: Hello, please see my edited question. I also tried with object and it did not work. I added what console.log shows me and what the Criteo site error is.

Comment: Is it because the comma sign is missing? Because according to Criteo, each line should have a comma in the end. How can I add this in an object?

Comment: Show us the code you use to push your objects

Comment: I just added the code, thanks for trying to help me out

Comment: What is `allitems` ?

Comment: An empty array which is populated with the full line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var firstLine = {
  product_id: "20020-278",
  price: "119",
  quantity: "1"
};
var secondLine = {
  product_id: "20009-129",
  price: "927",
  quantity: "3"
};

var items = [];
items.push(firstLine);
items.push(secondLine);

var myObj = {
  event: "viewBasket",
  item: items
};

console.log(myObj);

//window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
//window.criteo_q.push({
//  event: "setAccount",
//  account: 11111
//}, {
//  event: "setEmail",
//  email: "username@domain.com"
//}, {
//  event: "setSiteType",
//  type: "d"
//}, myObj);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. Will give it a try now and let you know

Comment: I tried it but it prints the same error "Product ID info missing: "item" property is missing". Maybe it has something to do with the object structure again? not sure exactly :( I changed my code as you suggested but still not working.

Comment: Show me the final object

Comment: You should check what you have to send to criterio. You are certainly missing some info

Comment: You can see in the first code I posted in my post what they need. And it is exactly what we are passing in there. But they do have a **comma** sign in the end of each line. Would that be the problem maybe? Template from Criteo: **{ id: "product_id_1", price: price_1, quantity: quantity_1 },**

Comment: Hello again, I finally found my silly mistake. I was using "product_id: 20020-278" instead of "id: 20020-278". Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you